# TypeScript equivalent of rest/spread props in React stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add the following function, taken from `bootstrap-react` [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms-controls), to my TypeScript + React project:

```
function FieldGroup({ id, label, help, ...props }) {
    return (
        <FormGroup controlId={id}>
            <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl {...props} />
            {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
        </FormGroup>
    );
}
```

However the rest/spread properties for ECMAScript 6 used as arguments are not supported by TypeScript versions < 2.1.

My current implementation is:

```
interface FieldGroupProps extends React.HTMLAttributes {
    id?: string;
    label?: string;
    help?: string;
}

class FieldGroup extends React.Component<FieldGroupProps, {}> {
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        const rest = objectWithout(this.props, ["id", "label", "help"]);
        return (
            <FormGroup controlId={this.props.id}>
                <ControlLabel>{this.props.label}</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl {...rest} />
                {this.props.help && <HelpBlock>{this.props.help}</HelpBlock>}
            </FormGroup>
        );
    }
}
```

Is this functionally (not from a performance perspective) equivalent to the ECMAScript 6 version? If I missed something or it could be made more elegant, what is the recommended way to translate the use of the above rest/spread syntax?

Comment: See how babe transpiles rest/spread arguments. https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20FieldGroup(%7B%20id%2C%20label%2C%20help%2C%20...props%20%7D)%20%7B%7D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In TypeScript 3, your first example will work fine so you don't need to rewrite it into a class.

If you like, you can also use your `FieldGroupProps` interface as well as rewriting it into an arrow function.

```
const FieldGroup = ({ id, label, help, ...props }: FieldGroupProps) => <FormGroup controlId={id}>
    <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
    <FormControl {...props} />
    {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
</FormGroup>;
```